# Accessing Custom Annotation Enumerator Type Not Working

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, annotations, mkmapview, getter

Hey, I am having problems accessing a variable within a custom annotation class I defined. Here is the relevant code:

ArboretumAnnotation.h(custom annotation class header):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
typedef enum { //correspond to permit types
    arboAnnoTypeNone = 0,
    arboAnnoTypeShieldsOakGrove
} arboAnnoType;

@interface ArboretumAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {
    NSString *title;
    NSString *subtitle;
    UIImage *image;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    arboAnnoType annotEnumType;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *subtitle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *image;

@property (nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic) arboAnnoType annotEnumType;

@end
```

Please note that all declared properties have been synthesized in the implementation file.

MapViewController.m:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView 
 annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{

    //show detail view but first set the view with the appropriate title
    LocationDetailViewController *locationDetail = [[LocationDetailViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    NSLog(@"permitDetail.title: %@", locationDetail.title);
    if (view.annotation.annotEnumType == arboAnnoTypeShieldsOakGrove) { //PROBLEM LINE
        locationDetail.title = @"Shields Oak Grove";
        locationDetail.annotEnumType = arboAnnoTypeShieldsOakGrove;
    }
    else {
        locationDetail.title = view.annotation.title;
        locationDetail.annotEnumType = arboAnnoTypeNone;
    }
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:locationDetail animated:YES];
    [locationDetail release];

}
```

At the line with the comment: `//PROBLEM LINE` I am getting the following error:

```
MapViewController.m:148: error: accessing unknown 'annotEnumType' getter method
```

Even if I change that line to:

```
if ([view.annotation annotEnumType] == arboAnnoTypeShieldsOakGrove) {
```

I get the following warning:

```
MapViewController.m:148: warning: '-annotEnumType' not found in protocol(s)
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to first cast it to your custom annotation type because the annotation property by itself is just `id<MKAnnotation>`:

```
ArboretumAnnotation *arboretumAnnot = (ArboretumAnnotation *)view.annotation;
if (arboretumAnnot.annotEnumType == arboAnnoTypeShieldsOakGrove) {
```